# Vue.js poor binding performance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I came across a performance problem that boggles my mind.
Given the following component:

```
<template lang="pug">
div
  div {{ counter }}
  div(v-for="idx in new Array(10000).keys()", :key="idx")
    b-button(v-on:click="increment()") ++
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Test extends Vue {
  private counter = 0;

  increment() {
    console.log(Date.now());
    this.counter++;
  }
}
</script>
```

I expect that when I change `counter` vue does not rerender the full component. It seems I am wrong I get horrible performance when `counter` is changed. Am I missing something, is it how vue is supposed to work?

### UPDATE

I replaced the `new Array(10000).keys()` call with a precomputed value but performance stays the same. Replacing `b-button` with a regular button improves performance significantly which indicates to me that for some reason all the buttons are recreated every time `counter` changes.

```
<template lang="pug">
div
  div {{ counter }}
  div(v-for="idx in keys", :key="idx")
    b-button(v-on:click="increment()") ++
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Test extends Vue {
  private counter = 0;
  private keys = [...new Array(10000).keys()];

  increment() {
    console.log(Date.now());
    this.counter++;
  }
}
</script>
```

### UPDATE

Removing the `div {{ counter }}` binding gives perfect performance (e.g. replacing with `div 0`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a function inside and creating a new instance in the loop and then looping over it, so every time the **counter** update, that "new Array" again initiate.

**UPDATE**

The problem is with your "new Array(100).keys()", whenever you update "counter", it re-renders because of that.

And if you use instead of that place, normal array data, it will work and you won't get a re-render issue.

**Use computed property**:

```
dataArrayKey () {
            return [...new Array(10000).keys()]
          }
```

**And then in the loop, use the computed property array, like this:**

```
<template lang="pug">
div
  div {{ counter }}
  div(v-for="idx in dataArrayKey", :key="idx")
    b-button(v-on:click="increment()", :key="idx + '-button'") ++
</template>
```

Comment: It is probably not that, even if I use computed property performance stays similar. Replacing b-button with regular button improves performance significantly, which indicates to me that it is probably recreating all the buttons for some reason every time counter changes.

Comment: @MarcinKról Got the problem, the problem is with this "new Array(100).keys()", it is normal Array and when you update, the Vue computed property thinks that you updated " Array(100).keys()", if you just use a normal array with data, it will fix your issue.

Comment: I replaced it with `[...new Array(10000).keys()]`, I believe it creates a regular array. Unfortunately it changes nothing. Removing the `{{ counter }}` binding fixes performance so would it be the case if it was a problem with the array?

Comment: @MarcinKról with that clone array (with spread operator) in computed property, it also works.The problem is not the counter, it's I believe your "b-button" component. Maybe try to add "key" to it, it can fix the re-rendering issue.

Comment: It seems like the best option for now is to replace b-button (boostrap-vue component) with regular button. For some reason it is very inefficient. It is some very strange vue behavior though. This `counter` binding should in no way influence the b-button components.